# Generating a histogram from a matrix table

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I have the following example table:

```
group_a = {'ba':[2.0,9.4,10.8],
          'bb':[4.2,7.1,3],
          'bc':[8.1,9.5,6.1]}

A = pd.DataFrame(group_a, index=['aa','ab','ac'])
```

That looks like this

```
    ba   bb   bc
aa  2.0  4.2  8.1
ab  9.4  7.1  9.5
ac  10.8 3.0  6.1
```

It reads somewhat like a multiplication table [aa * ba = 2.0 etc.] I would like to generate a histogram where the x axis represents the values (bins) and the y axis is the number of pair interactions that fall into each bin. I'm just unsure how to attempt this with this table structure.

Comment: Just `np.histogram(A, bins=np.arange(12))`? Or, for the plot: `plt.hist(A, bins=np.arange(12))`? (you can also pass, e.g. `bins=10`).

Comment: So I've been playing around with this but it doesn't seem to generate what I'm looking for. Lets say I wanted 3 groups on my x axis. Ranges [2.0,4.5],[4.5,7.5],[7.5,10.8]. From the table, I would expect a histogram that shows 3 pair interactions in range [2.0,4.5], 2 in range [4.5,7.5] and 4 in range [7.5,10.8].

Comment: Pass bins=[2, 4.5, 7.5, 11]?